# npm install ERR code E404 or code ENOENT

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, antd

my node version 8.9.1 ;

npm version 5.5.1;

when i try to install modules by npm,the ERR reported like 'code E404' or 'code ENOENT'；

I try to install different modules ,such as ‘tldr’ for global or ‘babel-plugin-import’ for my project called ‘dvaDemo’
 **The dvaDemo is an antd project creating by dva-cli**

```
npm i  babel-plugin-import --save
npm i tldr -g
```

Answer (score 0):

check your npm registry:

```
npm get registry
```

it might be something else than "https://registry.npmjs.org/", if so either install specific package with ending `--registry="https://registry.npmjs.org/"` for example

```
git install babel-plugin-import --registry="https://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

or just run this:

```
npm set registry --registry="https://registry.npmjs.org/"
```